# What is a common/recommended hosting service for Solana Applications?

Tags: anchor, react, webapp

I am building an web based application with React and Anchor. I would like to host this site so users can access, preferably the cheapest option. :)

Comment: Unfortunately this is much too opinionated and outside of the scope of Solana. Please look to traditional hosting services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cheapest option is usually hosting it on your own server.
The most comfortable option is probably vercel.
You can just host your application directly from your github repository and many people use that.